# Infinite loop on react ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs

I have a model called Event, after updating the Event, when I try to update the change to the view with componentDidUpdate it keeps looping forever (infinite loop). I have searched and saw people that had the same problem but I can't seem to get it working.

here is my componentDidUpdate inside `EventComments` component

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  axios
  .get(
    "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
      this.props.match.params.id +
      "/eventcomments"
  )
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ event: response.data });
    this.setState({ eventcomments: response.data.eventcomments });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Please what should I do to get this infinite loop to stop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your event in a conditional. Reference from the docs:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Your example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if(prevProps.id !== this.props.match.params.id){
  axios
  .get(
    "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
      this.props.match.params.id +
      "/eventcomments"
  )
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ event: response.data });
    this.setState({ eventcomments: response.data.eventcomments });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
}
```

Comment: i am new to React, i started to react less than two weeks ago. please can you throw more light to your example code, I went through react componentDidUpdate and it's the same example with what you have given me. i have tried to implement it in so many ways but didn't succeed. i did console.log(prevProps) and I saw that it was returning an object, containing my routing URL. what I updated on my Event model is an attribute called coming_with. if I do this.state.event.coming_with.length, I get the length of my event, how do I compare it after it gets updated? @Hyetigran

Comment: Welcome to React, I think you're going to like it! I think your conditional should be `this.state.event_with.length !== prevProps.event.coming_with.length`. If that doesn't work, could you share your entire component.

Answer (score 0):

after so many tries, I have managed to make it work. but, if you know a better way of doing it than this, please let me know.

Here is my what I did

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
if (prevState.event === this.state.event) {
  axios
    .get(
      "http://localhost:9000/events/" +
        this.props.match.params.id +
        "/eventcomments"
    )
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ event: response.data });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```